# Why copy constructor is called instead of move constructor with an rvalue initializer?

Tags: c++

Here is the definition of `SimpleString`. It implements both copy constructor and move constructor.

```
struct SimpleString {
  SimpleString(size_t max_size)
      : max_size{ max_size }
      , length{}  {
    if(max_size == 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error{ "Max size must be at least 1." };
    }
    buffer = new char[max_size];
    buffer[0] = 0;
  }
  ~SimpleString() {
    delete[] buffer;
  }
  SimpleString(const SimpleString& other)
      : max_size{ other.max_size }
      , buffer{ new char[other.max_size] }
      , length{ other.length } {
        puts("copy constructor");
    std::strncpy(buffer, other.buffer, max_size);
  }
  SimpleString(SimpleString&& other) noexcept
      : max_size(other.max_size)
      , buffer(other.buffer)
      , length(other.length) {
        puts("move constructor");
    other.length = 0;
    other.buffer = nullptr;
    other.max_size = 0;
  }

  void print(const char* tag) const {
    printf("%s: %s", tag, buffer);
  }
  bool append_line(const char* x) {
    const auto x_len = strlen(x);
    if(x_len + length + 2 > max_size)
      return false;
    std::strncpy(buffer + length, x, max_size - length);
    length += x_len;
    buffer[length++] = '\n';
    buffer[length] = 0;
    return true;
  }

  size_t max_size;
  char* buffer;
  size_t length;
};
```

I implement `+` operator.

```
SimpleString operator+(const SimpleString& str_1, const SimpleString& str_2) noexcept {
    SimpleString str_3{str_1}; // copy
    str_3.append_line(str_2.buffer);
    str_3.buffer[str_3.length-1]='\0';
    return str_3;
}
```

Does this function return an rvalue?

In c++ primer(5th):

> Functions that return a nonreference type, along with the arithmetic, relational, bitwise, and postfix increment/decrement operators, all yield rvalues.

So I think `operator+` return an rvalue.

```
int main() {
  SimpleString a{ 50 };
  a.append_line("We apologise for the");
  SimpleString b{ 50 };
  b.append_line("Last message");
    auto c = a+b; // copy constructor
    c.print("c");
}
```

I thought it would call the move constructor and print `move constructor`, because `a+b` is an rvalue.

But the output is:

```
copy constructor
c: We apologise for the
Last message
```

Why the move constructor is not called?

Comment: The copy constructor is called where you marked `// copy`. The RVO applied on return, no one constructor called.

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374506/5552166)

Comment: Don't forget the rule of five. You will also need to implement the copy and move assignment operator, or you will run into problems later.

Comment: @S.M. That's the aswer, why a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Because of copy elision, or else return value optimization (RVO)
[here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)!

It happens because the class type and the returned type are the same types.

So, the compiler instead of constructing the object `str_3` in a place in memory, and afterward copy/move it, it (more optimally) construct it in-place!

I think you can enforce the usage of the move constructor by specifying:

`return std::move(str_3)`

*I had the same question in the past, but for some reason they closed it...*
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192052/i-cannot-see-my-user-defined-copy-constructor-called-when-i-return-the-class-by)!